# Is it possible to add loading bar

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, webview

I am developing a cordova mobile app. In this app it is loading an a external page link. For example I am loading http://www.google.com.

After loading the page, I click on the links inside the page, but the links take some time to load. I want to show a progress on the time of loading.

I got some code from http://www.nacios.it/phonegap-progress-dialog-android/. But it shows an error in Java files.

Is there any other way to show a loading bar on webview?

Comment: are you using inappbrowser? or loading the external link by jquery?

Comment: by jquery. my code is window.location.replace("http://www.google.com/");

Comment: The webview completely loads the external page. So if you like to show loader you have to write script in the external page.

Comment: Is it possible load image with loading the script in mobile app